# rMBP kernel_task spikes when connecting more than one external monitor

Tags: display, macbook-pro, hdmi

When connecting a second external monitor kernel_task spikes to 600%+. This makes the computer unusable.

Before Yosemite, this worked fine with 3 monitors.

Here are the specifics:

- When I connect one monitor to either DP or HDMI things work fine.
- When I connect a second monitor with either DP or HDMI kernel_task spikes.
- When I disconnect either the DP or HDMI *sometimes* the kernel_task rapidly returns to normal levels.
- When I disconnect all monitors the kernel_task rapid returns to normal levels. (In Activity Monitor goto `View > Update Frequency > Very Often` and as soon as you disconnect the monitors, you will get lots of rapid updates to the UI).
- Occasionally when plugging in two monitors it works (DP or HDMI) but the 3rd causes an immediate spike. After this happens, all monitors must be removed for it to return to normal. *Sometimes* removing all but one will fix it.
- Sometimes when I plug all 3 in it takes 3 mins+ for it to occur.

What I have tried:

- Resetting NVRAM.
- Resetting SMC.
- Attempting the above scenario with power adapter plugged in and running on battery.
- Disabling "Automatic Graphics Switching" in Energy Saver.
- Using integrated graphics by using `sudo pmset -c gpuswitch 0`

*NOTE: When trying some of these things sometimes it takes 1min to happen.*

System config:

I am running a MacBook Pro Retina 2.7Ghz i7 (Macbook10,1 / Mid 2012) running Yosemite 10.10.1.

I have 3 external monitors (Dell 2415H) with 2 connected by Display Port and 1 with the HDMI.

---

I think the issue has to do with power management. Whenever my CPU hits 58 degrees it seems to occur. I just left my 3 monitors plugged in for 5+ mins and it didn't happen. But when I started searching using Chrome it immediately happened.

Looks like a good fix here: http://www.rdoxenham.com/?p=259

Comment: beside of CPU what other task goes up in activity?

Comment: Nothing, just kernel_task.

Comment: @bmike Why is this question marked as duplicate for a question that was asked later, and has a less complete accepted answer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find cause of high kernel\_task cpu usage?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/363337/how-to-find-cause-of-high-kernel-task-cpu-usage)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

According to [Rhys Oxenhams](http://www.rdoxenham.com/?p=259&cpage=2):

> the kernel will keep looping some very simple tasks, e.g. getting the date, 
>   therefore ‘consuming’ (with the highest priority) the majority of the CPU in a 
>   bid to cool the system down.

The solution he mentions on his blog should work for earlier Macs. For Ivy-Bridge Macs and a little earlier Richard Schwarting [has found the appropriate file to disable](http://blog.kosmokaryote.org/2012/12/technology-kerneltask-consumes-almost.html). Instructions are included below for convenience. I have tried many things, but this works.

1. Disable kext by renaming it

   ```
   cd /System/Library/Extensions/IOPlatformPluginFamily.kext/Contents/Plugins
   sudo mv X86PlatformShim.kext X86PlatformShim.kext.disabled
   ```
2. Clear kext cache (not sure if this is needed)

   ```
   sudo touch /System/Library/Extensions/
   ```
3. Restart

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```

---

- After installing OSX updates you may need to repeat the above procedure if the updates have re-created the `kext`.

### Update for (High) Sierra:

#### TL:TR

Rename IOPlatformPluginFamily.kext/ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin.kext/[MacModelIdentifier].plist

#### Step by step:

1. Start intro Recovery Mode (press CMD + R while startup)
2. Utility > Terminal `csrutil disable` (Disable system file protection)
3. Restart and rename `/System/Library/Extensions/IOPlatformPluginFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin.kext/Contents/Resources/[MacModelIdentifier].plist` (Mac > About > System Report > Model Identifier) to `bugfix.plist` (or something else)
4. Restart and check if `kernal_task` process is down below 10%
5. If successful restart again in Recovery Mode and enable system protaction again with `csrutil enable`

Tested and worked for me at 10.13.2 on Early 2011 MacbookPro.

Source with pictures (german)
http://www.couchpiratin.de/mac-zu-langsam-kernel_task-cpu-fehler-beseitigen/

Comment: 2 weeks later this has still resolved the issue. But I have also disabled `Settings > Mission Control > Separate spaces for displays` which stops the lag from focusing windows on different displays.

Comment: THANK you for posting this answer. I work on 3 monitors (same idea 2 DP 1 HDMI) and have to unplug my HDMI every day after about 10 minutes of use. Sometimes i'll get lucky and have a few hours, but anytime I play media (music, videos, etc) it'll spike and need to be disconnected.

Comment: Even with sudo getting `mv: rename X86PlatformShim.kext to X86PlatformShim.kext.disabled: Operation not permitted` when trying to move...

Comment: @Shwaydogg You probably need to disable OSX SIP. See http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x/

Comment: This is the correct answer. Why this question is marked as duplicate and says it already has an answer is crazy to me. Thanks so much for looking into the help.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this! I'd written off being able to use my old 27inch imac with my macbook pro. I had to disable SIP but it works perfectly.

Comment: @opsb Cheers! Also, make sure you keep your graphics card cool. GeForce cards have built-in temperature-sensitive processor speed throttling which is impossible to disable. I highly recommend: https://www.bresink.com/osx/HardwareMonitor.html for monitoring the temps with graphs. I have a small $20 desk fan pointed at the left-top of my mid-2012 rMBP at all times. Otherwise, I see big performance issues with 2 external monitors.

Comment: I'm in Barcelona so I do have a fan running constantly anyway just to keep me fresh ;) Haven't noticed any spikes apart from when I'm using hangouts, I just detach the extra screen while I'm on a call.

Comment: This seems to have worked for me.  I will add that I use a Logitech mouse, and I had to reinstall it's drivers to get the scroll wheel to work again.

Comment: @bheussler Interesting. I use an IntelliMouse Explorer from the 90s and I had to reinstall its drivers as well, but I never thought about the link to this kext.

Comment: Just following up.  I just had kernal_task spike out of control again.  Everything seemed to be fixed and working fine for a month.  I wonder if I applied an update and have to disable kext again?  Or maybe this was temperature related?  I'll try to keep you guys up to date.

Comment: @bheussler After each OSX update, it seems to restore the kext so you will probably have to perform fix again.

Comment: @vauhan Thank you for the response!  Maybe it's worth adding a note to the bottom of the answer.

Comment: Update: I am running Sierra and I'm having issues with the kernal_task again.  This solution is not enough anymore.

Comment: Same here. The solution didn't work for Sierra. Even after renaming and restarting, kernel_task went back to using 500% CPU.

Comment: I depends what Macbook you have. This works on my MBP Mid-2012 with NVidia graphics. It won't work for other laptops. I am using MBP 2016 with Sierra and no longer encounter these issues.

Comment: The solution works, but so much as an iTunes update and my MBP is back to being nearly unusable due to that issue. There simply has to be a better solution.

Comment: I can confirm that this works on macOS High Sierra beta 3... in fact, in my case, I didn't even need to restart.

Comment: I get `mv: rename X86PlatformShim.kext to X86PlatformShim.kext.disabled: Operation not permitted`. macOS Sierra.

Comment: @sharpmachine make sure SIP is disabled before attempting to renmae that file

Comment: I was trying to follow the update. In my case of 10.13.1 high Sierra, there was no file matching the pattern mentioned.

Comment: My model identifier says MacBookPro11,3 but there is no 11,3 plist file. Which one do i need to rename?

Comment: This was working until there was an update to Sierra, then I upgraded to High Sierra, also doesn't work. I checked if the kexts are recreated but unfortunately, that's not the case. We need another solution now

Comment: Any updates?  Same problem here - without the big screen, the computer works fine, but I _need_ both to view both code (on laptop) and 'result' (on big screen).

Comment: I am having following error on OS Catalina: `mv: rename X86PlatformShim.kext to X86PlatformShim.kext.disabled: Read-only file system
`

Comment: Has anyone found a solution for Mojave?

Answer (score 0):

I spend multiple days before finding out the solution that worked for me. Just try using a different charging cable. Your Macbook is plenty capable of working with multiple monitors, but frayed/internally damaged cables can cause strangely cause the kernel to enter into an infinite loop.